# Error: The superclass, 'Bloc', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments. class OverViewListBloc extends Bloc<OListEvent, List<OList>> {

Tags: flutter, run-app

Why did this error occur?:

```
Error: The superclass, 'Bloc', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
class OverViewListBloc extends Bloc<OListEvent, List<OList>> {
```

I could fix it with `OverViewListBloc(List<OList> initialState) : super(initialState);`, but I don't want to fix it this way, because I have to give an argument.

This is my code:

```
class OverViewListBloc extends Bloc<OListEvent, List<OList>> {
  OverViewListBloc(List<OList> initialState) : super(initialState);

  List<OList> get initialState => List<OList>();

  @override
  Stream<List<OList>> mapEventToState(OListEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SetList) {
      yield event.foodList;
    } else if (event is AddList) {
      List<OList> newState = List.from(state);
      if (event.newolist != null) {
        newState.add(event.newolist);
      }
      yield newState;
    } else if (event is DeleteList) {
      List<OList> newState = List.from(state);
      newState.removeAt(event.olistindex);
      yield newState;
    } else if (event is UpdateList) {
      List<OList> newState = List.from(state);
      newState[event.listIndex] = event.newolist;
      yield newState;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bloc changed the way it sets the initial state:

This line is no longer needed:

```
List<OList> get initialState => List<OList>();
```

instead you pass that value into the constructor:

```
OverViewListBloc() : super(List<OList>());
```

---

With the new [dart-null-safety](/questions/tagged/dart-null-safety) feature deprecating the empty constructor of `List<>`, you can just use

```
OverViewListBloc() : super(<OList>[]);
```